# VPN IP Routing - slow connections

Tags: vpn, local-area-network, pptp, site-to-site-vpn

UPDATE: Router error logs show:

```
LCP Time-out 0
```

I'm not sure how to correct this. The Lan-to-Lan profiles are set to -1 Idle Timeout (for the remote branch).

I have a PPTP VPN running between two Draytek 2820 routers. They are setup that one dials out to the other one.

```
Main Practice - 192.168.1.0/24
Branch        - 192.168.3.0/24
```

I have then set (on the Branch) router the following route:

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

If I then request a server running on 192.168.1.1 from the Branch, it correctly routes through VPN tunnel. If I request the branch server at 192.168.3.1 it correctly routes to the local server without using the VPN tunnel.

I have temporarily disabled the firewall on both routers, and made sure that QoS is disabled.

The Main Practice internet connection is ~30mb down / ~10mb up, and the Branch connection is ~5mb down / ~2mb up.

Anything over the VPN tunnel runs pretty slowly (VNC, Remote Desktop and Terminal Emulators). However, if I dial using the Windows VPN wizard, creating a connection from the laptop to the Main Practice - everything runs quickly.

I'm looking for possible causes, and/or ways of further diagnosing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: In summary, when I connect within the Branch and try and access a host that's within the Main Practice it works, but slowly. If I then dial the VPN on my Windows 7 laptop whilst still connected to the Branch network, it's fast.

**Main Practice**
[image: Main Practice]
**Branch Practice**
[image: Branch Practice]

**Routing Table from Branch Router**

```
Key: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, * - default, ~ - private
*            0.0.0.0/ 0.0.0.0          via 126.256.126.103   WAN2
C~      192.168.1.99/ 255.255.255.255  directly connected   VPN-1
S~       192.168.1.0/ 255.255.255.0    via 192.168.1.99     VPN-1
S~       192.168.2.0/ 255.255.255.0    via 192.168.1.99     VPN-1
C~       192.168.3.0/ 255.255.255.0    directly connected    LAN2
C    126.256.126.103/ 255.255.255.224  directly connected    WAN2
```

**Routing Table from Main Practice**

```
Key: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, * - default, ~ - private
*             0.0.0.0/         0.0.0.0 via 81.139.64.1,   WAN2
S        81.137.176.1/ 255.255.255.255 via 81.137.176.1,   WAN2
*         81.139.64.1/ 255.255.255.255 via 81.139.64.1,   WAN2
C~      192.168.1.204/ 255.255.255.255 is directly connected,    VPN
C~        192.168.1.0/   255.255.255.0 is directly connected,    LAN
S~        192.168.2.0/   255.255.255.0 via 192.168.1.204,    VPN
S~        192.168.3.0/   255.255.255.0 via 192.168.1.203,    VPN
```

**Connection Details (from Branch Router)**

[image: Connection details from Branch Router]

**Connection Details (from Main Practice Router)**

[image: Connection details from Main Practice Router]

**IPERF.exe Output**
[image: IPERF.exe output]

If it helps, here is the output from the IPERF.exe server

[image: IPERF.exe server]

Comment: I'm not understanding the question or the problem. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: Sorry, hopefully it's clearer now?

Comment: fyi you don't need to specify the route manually as VPN remote subnets are added to the routing table anyway

Comment: also can you detail the options used in your lan-to-lan profile

Comment: I've added some screenshots of the lan-to-lan setups. I didn't realise I didn't have to explicitly set the routes.

Comment: aye the routing table is under Diagnostics, i'd imagine with the IPSec tunnel you are limited to a maximum connection speed of 2Mbps (since this is the lowest speed on both connections), but when you connect directly to the main router it has a considerably faster upload speed. you can verify the actual connection speed on the Connection Management page.

Comment: I've added the output of the routing table (from the Branch) and the connection management screenshot to my question. The routing table looks ok to me, no loops etc. that I can tell.

Comment: Can you post the output of the interfaces for both connections?

Comment: @Rowell, do you mean show the connection management screen for the Main Practice aswell?

Comment: I've added the routing table and connection management details from the Main Practice router.

Comment: I was referring to more detailed interface stats. Are there any errors on the interfaces?

Comment: @Rowell, sorry - I'm not sure where to find that information?

Comment: If it helps, the logs for the Branch router shows 'LCP Time-out 0'

Comment: A packet capture would help (to show dropped packets), but it may help to set the mtu of a two of the computers on both sides of the connection to 1400 to see if that helps.

Comment: If I connect to the VPN of the Branch (from home) and then run Wireshark whilst connecting to the Main Practice server, would that be ok?

Comment: I think a capture from the main location and the branch is required.

Comment: OK, so we have a subjective assessment of VPN performance... could you run `iperf` over the tunnel and tell us what you get?

Comment: ok, I'll run Wireshark from the two locations as soon as possible. I will make sure I am requesting something from the 'other' location.

Comment: I've run Wireshark at the Main Practice for a short time - https://gist.github.com/1363547

Comment: I have added the iperf output to the original question.

Comment: I've also run Wireshark at the Branch for a short time - https://gist.github.com/1363635

Comment: Did you ever get this solved. I am having exact same issues and for the life of me can not sort out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VPN connection uses MPPE encryption, but according to router's page http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/vigor2830.html - MPPE have no hardware support.
Try to setup something else as encryption protocol (AES/DES/3DES).
IMHO it is available only with L2TP protocol.

Comment: agreed, in this case try using an IPSec (AES) lan-to-lan profile instead of PPTP (uncheck the box for this on inbound)

Comment: It's looking likely that you've hit the nail on the head, I'll test some more and get back to you. Thanks!